# Windows form application c# spread text into different Textboxes

Tags: c#, string, textbox

I have a string or `TextBox` which contains three words.

There is one space between words, and I want to move each word to three different `TextBoxes` as shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnyNO.png)

```
string theString = "hardy majid Ali";

            txt_first.Text = ?????;
            txt_second.Text = ?????;
            txt_3rd.Text = ?????;
```

How to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

use split, like this code :

```
var strs = theString.Split(' ');
txt_first.Text = strs[0];
txt_second.Text = strs[1];
txt_3rd.Text = strs[2];
```